# Return url encoded problem with oauth client and IdentityServer4

Tags: angular, oauth, identityserver4

I've a weird problem with an angular client and IdentityServer4.
I'm using angular-auth-oidc-client for angular client and apache2 with ubuntu 16 for server.

When calling oidcSecurityService.authorize(), the redirectUrl is sent encoded, and IS4 responds with a "malformed redirect_uri" error.

Request:
https://epmid.xxxxxxx.com/connect/authorize?client_id=e3m&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fe3m.xxxxxxx.com&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20roles%20offline_access%20E3MApi&nonce=cff811f389293bc3bd905bfdc6c8614a02za6ShIX&state=a72e68d561a3777c10db97fc7898f754acYqmZJK1&code_challenge=qaXRF4swipqQn5ED7uJKAK_I0ErTOkx0Na7hvLaeFRY&code_challenge_method=S256

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URL seems to be URLEncoded twice?

Comment: Sorry, it's not double encoded. Has been an error with copy/paste.